# GeoServing thousands of rasters, is there a limit on the number of images?

Tags: geoserver

I have a web application on which the users do some processing that outputs rasters. Those rasters are transferred to geoserver for later visualization through WMS.

The GeoServer is running on TomCat6, this geoserver is feeded daily with hundreds of ~2mb rasters.

A few days ago it reached ~3000 datastores (and layers) and it stopped responding every time a new raster is added, then it needs to be rebooted.

I followed the optimization guideline on the geoserver documentation and changed to Oracle Java and set the container options (more java memory and throughput garbage collector).

That solved the problem and it's running very fast.

But the number of rasters continues to increase and my question is if there is a limit on the number of raster stores that geoserver can handle so that I should expect to have the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to check out the new GeoServer beta release as it has a new module that addresses this issue. If you read

http://blog.geoserver.org/2013/01/29/geoserver-2-3-beta-released/

The module name is Pluggable configuration storage subsystem

"we’ve developed a new community module allowing configuration to be stored in a relational database and tests show good performance even with millions of layers stored in it"

Might be worth a go

Comment: How it should be installed/activated?